# Ĉu "deprimo" kaj "depresio" estas tute la samaj aferoj?

Tags: word-difference

En la Franca, "déprime" estas provizora, kelkfoje plurtaga malfeliĉeco. "Dépression" estas malsano, multe pli longa kaj kun multe pli da simptomoj.

Tamen, en Esperanto, Vortaro.net kelkfoje egaligas "deprimo" al "depresio", kaj Reta Vortaro kelkfoje egaligas "depresio" al "deprimo".

Ĉu oni povas diri ke en la senco de psika malvigleco, ambaŭ vortoj samsignifas?

Answer (score 4):

Mi dirus, ke ***jes.*** Se entute diferenco ekzistas (kaj tion mi pridubas), temas pri diferenco de *registro,* ne de signifo. *Depresio* estas medicina vorto, *deprimo* komun-uza, kaj ili ambaŭ signifas *kaj* la malsanon *kaj* la animstaton. Se ekestas duboj, pri kiu signifo temas, mi uzas *klinika depresio* unuflanke, kaj esprimojn kiel *energimanko, mishumoro,  malfeliĉeco* aliflanke.

***Redakto:*** Diferenco kompreneble estas, ke *depresio* havas ankaŭ aliajn signifojn: geografian *(La depresio de Arundo)*, ekonomikan *(ekonomia depresio)*, ktp. kaj mi hezitus uzi *deprimo* por ili. Aliflanke, ilia ĉeesto malfaciligas kalkuli per guglotrafoj, kiom pli ofta estas *deprimo* en la ĉi tie pritraktata senco.

Tamen, eblas konstati, ke dum *deprimiĝi* estas ĉiutaga vorto, *depresiiĝi* estas multe pli malofta, kaj estas uzata precipe en socia, ekonomika signifo (*la ĉina filmo depresiiĝis,* *manfarado de tolaj ŝuoj depresiiĝis,* ktp), malgraŭ la kontraŭa ekzemplo ĉe [Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/epo/sentences/show/1033509): *Je pluvotagoj mi depresiiĝas.*

Answer (score 1):

Mi supozos ke vi jam kontrolis en PIV kaj vidis ke la respondo estas ke jes. La dua difino de "deprimo" estas "depresio". Tiu estas nur unu ekzemplo de multaj balastaj vortoj en PIV.